# Is it okay to throw Exception in try catch block depending on if condition to stop executing try block and start executing catch block?

Tags: javascript, exception, try-catch

Example

```
try {
      let items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))
      if(items.length === 0){
          throw new Exception()    
      }
      // other code
      fetch('http://localhost:9004/merge-items').then(...)
}catch(e){
      console.error(e)
      fetch('http://localhost:9004/load-items').then(...)
}
```

I throw exception inside if block because I need to write similar code as inside catch block

```
try {
      let items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))
      if(items.length === 0){
           fetch('http://localhost:9004/load-items').then(...)   // The same code
      }
      // other code
      fetch('http://localhost:9004/merge-items').then(...)
}catch(e){
      console.error(e)
      fetch('http://localhost:9004/load-items').then(...) // The same code
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) *"Is it okay?"* asks for opinion, which is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking only if it is OK, then "no", it is not OK.

You can treat exceptions as something you do not expect, but you predict that. In your code you expect, that sometimes (on the start?) your local storage items can be empty.

So, better:

```js
const loadItems = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:9004/load-items').then(...)   // The same code
}

try {
  let items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))
  if (items.length === 0) {
    loadItems();
  }
  // other code
  fetch('http://localhost:9004/merge-items').then(...)
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
  loadItems();
}
```

Comment: Ok, but why should you do loadItems() in the catch block? Or the fetching of items in the original question, in the catch block? You already check if there are no items in local memory.

Comment: @Karlan because topic starter says: "because I need to write similar code as inside catch block". I don't know why he need this.